# bash reading and writing a config file with an unusual layout

Tags: bash, key, config, key-value, quotation-marks

**Question 1**
I have a config file written by a program which I want to overwrite the values by running a script in terminal.

The config file is laid out like so (there is probably a name for this format, but I don't know what it is):

```
name_1 = "value1"
name_2 = "value2"
...
```

The extra spaces I believe are what is causing the issue when I try to read the values in my script file as I get the error "command not found" for each name.

Is there anyway I can include this file in my bash script so it understand that each line is a variable?

**Question 2**
How can I overwrite values of single lines in that file with the same formatting? The quotation marks in the config file have me confused, as well as the space before and after the = symbol.

Would the following work?

```
CONFIG_FILE=test.cfg
TARGET_KEY=$"name_1 "
REPLACEMENT_VALUE=" "true" "
sed -i "s/\($TARGET_KEY *= *\).*/\1$REPLACEMENT_VALUE/" $CONFIG_FILE
```

Comment: Please avoid asking two questions as if they were one.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and correct your question due to instruction.

Comment: Relevant: [How to parse and convert ini file into bash array variables?](https://serverfault.com/questions/345665/how-to-parse-and-convert-ini-file-into-bash-array-variables) Why is everyone so focused on getting bash to do things it is not well suited for? These days everywhere there's bash, there's also likely higher order languages like Python or Ruby or Perl are present; Python has this built-in (as one of the answers in the link shows), while it's easy enough to code up in another higher language if you don't want to use a package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, pre-process your `.cfg` file and then read it, like this:

```
CONFIG_FILE=test.cfg
sed 's/ = /=/g' < test.cfg > /tmp/processed.cfg
. /tmp/processed.cfg
```

Now, all your `name_1`, `name_2` pairs will be available to your shell scripts.

For the second question, do it like this:

```
CONFIG_FILE=test.cfg
TARGET_KEY='name_1 '
REPLACEMENT_VALUE='"true" '
sed -i -e "s/\($TARGET_KEY *= *\).*/\1$REPLACEMENT_VALUE/" $CONFIG_FILE
```